# loop through posted values to see if any equal "no"

Tags: php

How can i loop through a post and find if any of the answers are "no"?

Here is my code so far:

```
if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"]) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        $_SESSION['minrequirements'][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"]) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ('no' == $value) {
            // do something
        } 
        $_SESSION['minrequirements'][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @netcoder yeah, but if you'r tired then yoda regards you with messages ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use in_array() or array_search() and save a loop:

```
if (in_array('no', $_POST)) echo 'they said no'.
if (($key = array_search('no', $_POST)) !== false) echo "$key was answered with no";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$NoAsnwers = false;
if($_POST["minRequirementsForm"]) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == 'No') $NoAsnwers = true;
    }
}
```

Maybe so?